# Bitcoin from an economic standpoint?

Tags: economic-theory, deflation, macroeconomics

Anybody have any good resources to learn about bitcoin from an economic standpoint?  Specifically discussing the debate around its deflationary nature?

Comment: Hi, user13977: As you discovered, we already have tags for [tag:economics] and [tag:deflation], it is possible that some of the questions tagged thusly will help you along the way of satisfying your curiosity.

Comment: You can easily find defenses galore of the system. For criticisms of Bitcoin from an economic POV, you can try reading Shelby Moore IIIs posts, both in this site and elsewhere on the net. Even if you don't completely agree with him you'll surely learn a thing or two.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, the deflationary aspects of Bitcoin are tied to the limited supply and  lack of central regulation. I'm still learning about it but here is a collection of articles I put together on the subject: http://wayfinder.co/pathways/530d0adaa30064b367000088/an-economic-primer-on-bitcoin

Answer (score 0):

One resource I can recommend is reviewing the [charts on blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info/charts).  There is tons of historical information you can gleam by analyzing what has happened previously.

Like past market price in USD, for example: [image]